# Finding text within complex html document structure with javascript

Tags: javascript, search

I am writing an automation script that will pull information from a dynamically generated webpage. I cannot control the information on it, thus I am having trouble referencing the information. The information I want is in a table, with a preceding keyword that will not change. The problem I have is it is not directly referenced. From the example below I need to get the claim # and policy #. The labels are always the same, and the actual numbers are always HTML-adjacent. But how can I reference them? I've tried x-path, javascript iteration, nodes...Nothing seems to work. Ideally I'd like a script where I can ask for

findMe ('Claim #') and it would return var claimNumber = '9999-99999'

Here is an example:

```
<tbody><tr>
<th id="cf_2727850_th" class="Form"><label for="cf_2727850">Claim #:</label></th>
<td id="cf_2727850_td" class="Form" name="td2" style="width: 346px;">9999-99999</td>
<th id="cf_2727851_th" class="Form"><label for="cf_2727851">Policy #:</label></th>
<td id="cf_2727851_td" class="Form" name="td2" style="width: 346px;">12500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="cf_1649747_th" class="Form"><label for="cf_1649747">Client First Name:</label></th>
<td id="cf_1649747_td" class="Form" name="td2" style="width: 346px;">JOHN</td>
<th id="cf_1649746_th" class="Form"><label for="cf_1649746">Client Middle Name:</label></th>
<td id="cf_1649746_td" class="Form" name="td2" style="width: 346px;"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="cf_1649719_th" class="Form"><label for="cf_1649719">Client Last Name:</label></th>
<td id="cf_1649719_td" class="Form" name="td2" style="width: 346px;">DOE</td>
<th id="cf_1649729_th" class="Form"><label for="cf_1649729">Client Date of Birth:</label></th>
<td id="cf_1649729_td" class="Form" name="td2" style="width: 346px;">1/1/1900</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th id="cf_1649730_th" class="Form"><label for="cf_1649730">Client Gender:</label></th>
<td id="cf_1649730_td" class="Form" name="td2" style="width: 346px;">Male</td>
<th id="cf_2727854_th" class="Form"><label for="cf_2727854">Date of Loss/Injury:</label></th>
<td id="cf_2727854_td" class="Form" name="td2" style="width: 346px;">04/15/2015</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks a lot!

PS. The body might have a few of those table, so the script would need to be generic.

Comment: If there are more than one `<tbody>` on the page can we assume the first `<tbody>` is the correct `Claim #` to be returned?

Comment: If you actually want to learn something, you should have posted what you have tried (together with what you expected to get and what you actually got). This way, others could point out your errors and you could learn from your errors.